# Confidence estimation for data points in a recommender system

Tags: confidence-interval, data-imputation, recommender-system

I have a 100 by 100 matrix. Each cell is either 0, 1, or missing (denoted NA). Rows denote 'users' and columns denote 'items'. My goal is to impute the missing values, and provide a confidence level for each imputed value.

To impute the missing values I have implemented a set of recommender systems including naive Bayes and k-Nearest Neighbours. I have calculated the mean accuracy (miss-classification rate), and standard deviation of this rate, for each recommender system, using 5-fold cross validation.

I would next like to calculate a level of confidence for each data point. However, I have only one data point for each user-item pair, so more well-researched methods are difficult to apply.

My solution is the following. I have run the cross validation process 20 times, each with a different splitting of the data set. This has provided 20 predictions for each data point, each based on a different subsample of the data. I have then calculated an estimated confidence for each data point as the following:

Number of correct predictions/Total number of predictions.

I interpret this as the probability of a correct prediction for a particular pair. Is this a principled metric to estimate confidence in this situation, and are there any other approaches that you recommend I look into?